# How to set headers in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I've been trying to speed up my websites performance and was told that I should gzip everything stuff before they are sent to the browser.

The solution I found(which I hope works) is to include the content-encoding header.

At the bottom of my app.js file I have this code

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(req,res){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
  res.setHeader("Content-Encoding","gzip");
});
```

I am receiving errors like this:

```
C:\Users\user\workspace\site\app.js:35
  res.setHeader("Content-Encoding","gzip");
      ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'setHeader' of undefined
```

Could you explain what is going wrong here? From what I know, the code has the proper syntax. What's the solution.

Also, this will speed up my website correct? (I'm not sure)

Another thing I know of is that headers should not be sent before the text. I think that may be my issue

Answer (score 3):

The callback passed to `listen()` does not have any parameters, it is only called when the server has bound to the port and is then listening.

For response compression, you might look at using the [compression](https://github.com/expressjs/compression) middleware instead of trying to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it,just use the route api like `get` or `post`.

Change your code to this:

```
app.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.setHeader("Content-Encoding","gzip");
});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```